# Customize form of a list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I want to customize a form with infopath in Sharepoint 2010. I know where should be the button : [image]

But in my browser and with my sharepoint's version I don't have the infopath button :
[image]

Can you tell me where I can find it, or how? Maybe I need the enterprise version of Sharepoint?
Thanks

Comment: Helpful answers already discussed here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18313/infopath-button-missing-in-ribbon-for-list

Comment: Is your "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features" activated in Site Collection Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so indeed I need the enterprise version

Comment: My question was : how to get the customize button in the ribbon. So have the enterprise version is an answer I think

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought you were looking for an anwer HOW to customize the form and not for the button. I will remove my previous comment.